# Responsive design or mobile version?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am about to start a new project and I want the design to be the best you can and quickly. My question is the following. Taking into account that I will use bootstrap was considering the option of creating a theme for PC and one for Mobile (m.example.com) but I think this is no longer correct (correct me if I'm wrong) then taking into account that PC design for responsive would be right to do the following: the "hide in mobile" bootstrap really have a proper use for many parts of the code? that is, the browser will load all this information and then hide it or this does not affect the loading time if a lot of code is hidden in the design?

Comment: `Taking into account that I will use bootstrap was considering the option of creating a theme for PC and one for Mobile (m.example.com) but I think this is no longer correct (correct me if I'm wrong)`, That is **correct**, assuming you design it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use responsive design when you make new website.
You use two separate sites (mobile and desktop) for existing desktop website in case client wants to safe some money. (but beware, two separate sites will cost more development time and money!)
Google advise ONE website (responsive one)
As for responsive/mobile first design you first make basic mobile website then let it expand. Almost any website that's handmade (by developer that knows what he's doing) will be way faster. Yet if you want to develop faster you can indeed use bootstrap for example.

Comment: ok I understand, then it is better created a single adaptive design. I would like to know your opinion on the following: In the desktop version 10 sections are shown in the hidden mobile 9 and left only 1 visible section. the other 9 hidden affect the loading time of the mobile version?

Comment: Hidden or not it will effect your loading times if it's in your html. I want to add that most of these "responsive" website are not responsive at all (in terms of load speeds) because of that issue your are mentioning. Ofc best performance will be with two separate websites.